# How to link two OpenID accounts into one internal account with Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security, openid

I have a working prototype web site that has OpenID logins based on Spring Security 3.2.0.M2 derived from [Spring Security's OpenID sample](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/tree/master/samples/openid-xml) that uses the [openid-selector](https://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/) project to select an OpenID provider.  Upon logging in I create an "internal" account in the database with a random UUID primary key that has the OpenID username as a column so I can find the same "internal" account later.

I want to add additional OpenID accounts to the same "internal" account in the same way that StackExchange does.  I can navigate to my `/login` JSP URL and with the `<sec:authentication property="principal.firstname" />` I can see my logged in info.  Without logging off from my site, if I click on a link to go to another OpenID provider from `/login` and log in, what is the recommended way to link the new OpenID login with same "internal" account when the browser returns to my site?  I presume that the cookie that identified the first login is reset upon the second login.

Is it recommended that I put a nonce cookie in the session so if it's seen on a new login then the site should ask if it should be added to the original "internal" account?  Should this nonce cookie only be added from `/login`?  Is this correct or is there a more secure way?  I'm thinking I should stay away from using email address to link the two OpenID accounts.